# Why does jpa/hibernate still perform a "select-then-update" when saving an entity that retrieved from "findBy" method, seems it was detached

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am building a blog website, and there are two types of entities that can be voted right now, the blog and the comment. I want to use one table to store these two types of vote counter. I think the `(entity_id, type)` pair can be the composite primary key, there's my Java @Entity base class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "vote_counter")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorOptions(insert = false)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class VoteCounter extends ManuallyAssignIdEntitySuperClass<VoteCounterId> {

    @EmbeddedId
    private VoteCounterId id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer voteCount = 0;

    public VoteCounterId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(VoteCounterId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getVoteCount() {
        return voteCount;
    }

    public void setVoteCount(Integer voteCount) {
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }

    public void incrVoteCount(int value){
        voteCount += value;
    }

    public void decrVoteCount(int value){
        voteCount -= value;
    }

    public VoteCounter() {
    }

    public VoteCounter(VoteCounterId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public VoteCounter(long entityId, int type){
        this.id = new VoteCounterId(entityId, type);
    }
}
```

I follow the tutorials [post](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites) and create the `ManuallyAssignIdEntitySuperClass`. And here's the `@EmbeddedId` class definition:

```java
@Embeddable
public class VoteCounterId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "entity_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long entityId;

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer type;

    public VoteCounterId() {
    }

    public VoteCounterId(Long entityId, Integer type) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Long getEntityId() {
        return entityId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof VoteCounterId)) return false;
        VoteCounterId that = (VoteCounterId) o;
        return Objects.equals(entityId, that.entityId) &&
            Objects.equals(type, that.type);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(entityId, type);
    }
}
```

The basic `VoteCounter` class has two subclass, `BlogVoteCounter` and `CommentVoteCounter`.

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(VoteType.COMMENT_DISCRIMINATOR)
public class CommentVoteCounter extends VoteCounter {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", updatable = false, nullable = false, insertable = false)
    private Comment comment;

    public CommentVoteCounter() {
    }

    public CommentVoteCounter(long commentId) {
        super(commentId, VoteType.COMMENT);
    }

    public Comment getComment() {
        return comment;
    }
}
```

I've create a method to test the behavior of these class. As you can see, the semantic here is like "check whether the `blogVoteCounter` is existed or not, if exist, increase its vote count, if not, just create one".

```java
    public BlogVoteCounter incrBlogVoteCounter(long id){
        return blogVoteCounterRepository.findByBlog(blogRepository.getOne(id)).map(blogVoteCounter -> {
            blogVoteCounter.incrVoteCount(1);
            return blogVoteCounterRepository.save(blogVoteCounter);
        }).orElseGet(() -> {
            BlogVoteCounter blogVoteCounter = new BlogVoteCounter(id);
            return blogVoteCounterRepository.save(blogVoteCounter);
        });
    }
```

Now here's the problem, after creating the initial `BlogVoteCounter` in database for a specific `Blog`, each time when i perform the method on that `Blog`, it seems that hibernate/jpa will always trigger a extra select query before `save`. just like:

```sql
Hibernate: 
    select
        blogvoteco0_.entity_id as entity_i2_8_,
        blogvoteco0_.type as type1_8_,
        blogvoteco0_.vote_count as vote_cou3_8_ 
    from
        vote_counter blogvoteco0_ 
    where
        blogvoteco0_.type=1 
        and blogvoteco0_.entity_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        blogvoteco0_.entity_id as entity_i2_8_0_,
        blogvoteco0_.type as type1_8_0_,
        blogvoteco0_.vote_count as vote_cou3_8_0_ 
    from
        vote_counter blogvoteco0_ 
    where
        blogvoteco0_.entity_id=? 
        and blogvoteco0_.type=? 
        and blogvoteco0_.type=1
Hibernate: 
    update
        vote_counter 
    set
        vote_count=? 
    where
        entity_id=? 
        and type=?
```

But if i add `@Transactional` annotation on `incrBlogVoteCounter` method, the extra select query before update will not appear. I am guessing that the `BlogVoteCounter` retrieved by `findByBlog` method is detached, thus the select query will be performed before update, but i just wonder why it will be detached(if my guess is write). I use the same pattern (find-and-update) in other place of my application, and all of them will not issue this problem. I want to know how to avoid this extra query?

Comment: By making the method transactional. It will be detached as soon as the `findBy` method has done executing as it now stands. So when saving it starts a new transaction and re-attaches the entity and thus needs to do a select. Your service method should be transactional as tha tis your unit-of-work. On a side note, you will also need a bit of versioning in your code, if now 2 votes come in, one will be lost.

Comment: @M.Deinum How two avoid the "one will be lost" situation, can you make it more clear? Besides, will it avoid this kind of error if i use query like ```update vote_counter set vote_count=vote_count+1```?

Comment: Not unless you either use pessimistic locking (locking the row in the database) or optimistic locking (include a version/timestamp in your entity).

Comment: @M.Deinum But will not the Innodb acquire lock while doing the ```update``` query?

Answer (score 0):

> but i just wonder why it will me detached

*Precisely because* the method is not wrapped in a transaction. In such a scenario, only the `findByBlog` creates its own transaction, and once the method call is finished, the persistence context gets cleared, and all the previously managed entities become detached.

If you're wondering *why* the additional select is performed *at all*, it's because `blogVoteCounterRepository.save(...)` invokes `EntityManager.merge()` internally. `EntityManager.merge()` needs to load the existing version of the entity into the persistence context in order to be able to perform the merge (hence the extra `SELECT`). When you use `@Transactional`, though, the entity is already in the context, so there's nothing to load (in fact, `EntityManager.merge()` has no effect).